# Guice: how do I bind generics for ALL types?

Tags: java, guice

Suppose I have the following pattern repeating often in my code:

```
class A<T> {
    @Inject
    public A(List<T> list) {
        // code
    }
}
```

I want to bind **all** `List<T>` to `ArrayList<T>`.
I know I can use `TypeLiteral`s to bind an explicit raw type, e.g., `List<String>`, but is there anyway to do this for all types?

Basically, this code should not fail because I didn't bind List explicitly:

```
injector.getInstance(new Key<A<Integer>>(){});
```

Comment: Based on what i found and tried so far. It is not possible.

Comment: Some discussion of this kind of "wildcard" binding can be found here: https://github.com/google/guice/issues/852

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible in Guice. Internally Guice is little more than a `HashMap<Key, Provider<?>>`, where a `Key` represents an optional binding annotation and a single fully-qualified type. To match a "pattern" of types would require a Key to behave more like a predicate, which would require a very different architecture and which would make binding lookup much slower.

Furthermore, though you may be using List for a simple example, remember that Guice bindings are better reserved for equivalent implementations that are likely to vary in production or tests. In addition to having very different algorithm-specific performance characteristics, List implementations vary in their ability to handle `null` items, and once you've picked an ideal list implementation for a given algorithm you're unlikely to need to change it—especially in an application-wide configuration.

If you do want to be able to vary your generic implementations with Guice-style configuration, create a very small factory like `ListFactory`:

```
public class ListFactory {
  public <T> List<T> createFooBarList() { return new ArrayList<T>(); }
  public <T> List<T> createSomeOtherList() { return new LinkedList<T>(); }
}
```