# How can I solve generis with Guice?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice, typeliteral

I have an abstract class for testing.

```java
abstract class EncoderTest<T extends Encoder> {

    public EncoderTest(final Class<T> type) {
        super();
        this.type = type;
    }

    @BeforeClass protected void inject() {
        createInjector(b -> b.bind(HexEncoder.class)
                .to(TypeLiteral.get(type)))
                .injectMembers(this);
    }

    private final Class<T> type;
    private T encoder;
}
```

**It works with subclasses.**

---

Now, another class uses that class as a delegate.

```java
abstract class SomeTest<E extends Encoder, D extends Decoder> {

    public SomeTest(final Class<E> encoderType,
                    final Class<D> decoderType) {
        super();
        encoderDelegate = new EncoderTest<E>(encoderType){
        };
        decoderDelegate = new DecoderTest<D>(decoderType){
        };
    }

    @BeforeClass protected void inject() {
        encoderDelegate.inject(); // ERROR!!!
        decoderDelegate.inject();
    }

    private final EncoderTest<E> encoderDelegate;
    private final DecoderTest<D> decoderDelegate;
}
```

And Guice throws an Error.

```
E cannot be used as a key; It is not fully specified.
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: If you are using a container for dependency injection, why are you creating new instances?

Comment: I already know TestNG supports Guice. I'm writing a technical article.

Comment: @TavianBarnes Fixed.

Comment: I can't reproduce this, can you give a complete, compilable example?

Comment: Check this link please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34176461/why-do-i-have-an-error-when-i-try-to-override-a-generic-binding-with-guice-typ/34794341#34794341

Comment: Guice doesn't support binding/injecting incomplete types as you have it. More here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/29676605/1426891